# Postgresql crosstab on multi pivoting and multi columns

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I’ve been trying to crosstab on multi pivots and multi columns

How do I go from

```
create table sales(year int, branch text, month int, qty int, scrap int, yield int);
insert into sales values(2007, 'Houston', 1, 1000, 66, 11);
insert into sales values(2007, 'Houston', 3, 1500, 55, 22);
insert into sales values(2007, 'Austin',  3,  500, 44, 33);
insert into sales values(2007, 'Laredo',  2, 1500, 77, 44);
insert into sales values(2007, 'El Paso', 2, 2000, 88, 55);
insert into sales values(2008, 'Waco',    1,  900, 99, 66);
```

to crosstab like this

```
 year | branch  | jan_qty | jan_scr | jan_yld | feb_qty | feb_scr | feb_yld | mar_qty | mar_scr | mar_yld
------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------
 2007 | Austin  |         |         |         |         |         |         |     500 |      44 |      33     
 2007 | El Paso |         |         |         |    2000 |      88 |      55 |         |         |     
 2007 | Houston |    1000 |      66 |      11 |         |         |         |    1500 |      55 |      22
 2007 | Laredo  |         |         |         |    1500 |      77 |      44 |         |         | 
 2008 | Waco    |     900 |      99 |      66 |         |         |         |         |         |
```

where both year and branch are pivots and each month contains 3 values?

Answer (score 0):

**1. The easiest route**

Is probably the following. It's not **DRY**, but it does the job, it's readable, works for any SQL flavor, and it can be easily generated by application code.

```
SELECT
  grain.year,
  grain.branch,
  (SELECT qty FROM sales WHERE sales.year = grain.year AND sales.branch = grain.branch AND sales.month = 1) AS jan_qty,
  (SELECT scr FROM sales WHERE sales.year = grain.year AND sales.branch = grain.branch AND sales.month = 1) AS jan_scr,
  (SELECT yld FROM sales WHERE sales.year = grain.year AND sales.branch = grain.branch AND sales.month = 1) AS jan_yld,
  ... same for feb ...,
  ... same for mar ...
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT year, branch FROM sales) grain
```

Application code just needs the names of the columns `jan_qty`, `jan_scr` ... to generate this SQL with a simple loop.

I would make sure to `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` the query above to check that PostgreSQL runs this query efficiently.

**2. The beautiful route**

This is a pivot table, and PostgreSQL gives us the [CROSSTAB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tablefunc.html) function for this kind of query. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query) perfectly explains how to do so, including  how to deal with missing values (i.e. empty cells in the result table), which is the case in the example you provided

Comment: tanks @Matthieu,  being honest, I had already seen the link that you give me but  I couldn't have several columns for the same month or several pivots. I ended up doing it manually with something similar to your easiest route. I'm still without crosstab